# outputting a coloured excel file, python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have been asked to write a program for the company I work for that will take an excel file and turn any filled out row and put a pink background on it, is it possible to take an excel file, add background colour and then to save the file, I am really struggling here so if anyone can give either a point in the right direction or a basic function I can model my code around it would be a huge help.

Comment: So, basically adding `conditional formatting`? Can you just use that feature in Excel itself rather than writing python? Or do you need code because this will apply to any number of excel files?

Comment: 100% yeah I overcomplicated this to hell

Comment: @isolated This may seem overcomplicated but it is possible that the company has a drive full of files they need formatted automatically. Writing a python script is way quicker more cost effective than paying someone to do it

Comment: @sconfluentus That's why I ended my first comment with that question. The OP didn't specific if this is one-time for a single file or something on a larger scale.

Comment: @isolated my bad, late day Friday

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an Excel workbook, you can read it in and edit directly on it, though until you get this down it may be better to keep the original and create a new one you can throw away without losing information.

It is a multi-step process:

Create the workbook and save it into a variable:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sample.xlsx')
```

Add a worksheet to the workbook

```
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
```

This worksheet now exists as an object in python's memory referenced by `worksheet` and as a sheet in the actual Excel workbook

You now need to write some data to that empty page:

```
worksheet.write(pandas_df) # this is where you drop in the data
```

Set a format to apply to your selection:

```
formats = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#F9DCD6',
                               'font_color': '#095A03'})
```

The next part is what you need to experiment with:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:Z100', {'type': 'cell',
                                     'criteria': '<your criteria>',
                                     'value': <your value>,
                                     'format': formats})
```

You can look up all the ways to identify different sorts of data here: [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html)

Within this there should be some way to create the scheme you are seeking.

Then you can just write it out as normal!

### Edit

Also, if you are reading the data into pandas and then creating new files, it might be easiest to simply apply the formatting to the table as you write it out. [This tutorial should get you there](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_xlsxwriter/python_xlsxwriter_fonts_and_colors.htm), just use the background color instead of font color: